# What is mean by--- List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>(4); in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to understand about this code, so please share your valuable guidelines.

```
List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>(4);
```

Comment: Default initialization size is 10 and here it is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java API for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

**Constructs an Element list with the initial capacity 4.**

```
List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>(4);
             Intializing List size as 4 here^
```

Comment: @user3550661 view the posted API doc. link

Answer (score 2):

This is an instantiation of an ArrayList of Element objects with an initial default capacity of 4.

Please refer to [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29)